# Background Image Not Appearing, Despite Appearing as Set in Browser Console

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I need to set the background image using PURE javascript (no JQuery or other libraries).

I set the background image using the javascript shown below. The Firefox console, inspector grid, and CSS engine all show that the background image is as it should be. I have successfully set the background color, showing that the element is not hidden, and I am not selecting the wrong element. As the code below shows, I have tried playing with the Opacity and the background color. This was fruitless. Upon hovering the image URL, Firefox shows that the image is in fact loaded correctly.

Here is my javascript:

```
var shadow = document.getElementById("shadow");
shadow.style.backgroundColor = "transparant";
shadow.style.opacity = "1";
shadow.style.backgroundImage = image;
```

CSS applied to the element when the program starts

```
div#shadow
{
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 315px;
    left: 721px;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
}
```

The element is just a div nested within the `<body>`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="shadow"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a mispelling. It's `transparent`, not `transparant`. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp

Comment: Your image variable needs to be in this format : "url('http://www.placehold.it/48x48')";
shadow.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://www.placehold.it/48x48')"; for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spelling error in transparent with the url of the image not just the name

```js
var shadow = document.getElementById("shadow");
shadow.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
shadow.style.opacity = "1";
shadow.style.backgroundImage = "url('image+address')";
```

```css
div#shadow
{
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 315px;
    left: 721px;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="shadow"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: True, but "transparent" is the default value for backgroundColor, so that line could probably removed.

Answer (score 0):

For the `style.backgroundImage` property, you need an image path, like `"url('image.png')"`. Otherwise, assign an image URL to the variable `image`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing way too much here. No `opacity` or `transparent` or `backgroundColor` is needed. Just set the `background` to the image.

But, in CSS whenever you need to supply a path for a property, you need to pass that path using the [`url()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url) function, which you don't appear to be doing.

```js
// Best practice: don't set individual properties on the 
// style of an element. Add/remove pre-made classes.
document.querySelector("div").classList.add("background");
```

```css
body { background-color:#e0e0e0; }
div { width:150px; height:150px; border:1px solid black; padding:10px;}

.background {
  /* Just set the background property using url(path). That's it. */
  background:url("http://www.thetherapystore.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/SSMILE.jpg");
  
  background-size:contain; /* Only used here to scale the image to fit */
}
```

```html
<div>This content is in the foreground.</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work as the background image is only discovered a few lines before the code shown.

Comment: @AdithyaLaakso What does that mean? Please clarify. If you must set the background using the `style` property fine, but you still have to set it up as I've shown here, using the `url()` function.

Comment: There are about 10,000 different background images that could potentially be chosen this list continuously grows almost daily. I cannot create a css class for all of them.

Comment: @AdithyaLaakso Yes, you've expressed that and I've said that you still are going to have to use the *url()* CSS function in order to set a background image in CSS. Just do it via JavaScript then, but you still have to set the background like this: `element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imagePathVariable + ")";`

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide your "image" var? I replaced you var with a url and it worked fine.

```
shadow.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://placehold.it/300x300')";
```

Also, try adding some background properties via CSS, maybe background-size.

Comment: The image var is equal to "url('sword.png')". I tried changing the backgroundSize. This did not help. I am not sure what other properties you want me to change.